# Nginx rewrite rules with query string arguments

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Here are my nginx rewrite rules

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.destination.com/main.php?utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=yyy&utm_campaign=zzz permanent;
```

Everything works so far except when there's query arguments.

This is a permanent 301 redirect, and I need to configure the case when there's query string, it will be appended before the utm tracking query.

How do I do this while also taking care of rewrite without query string?

eg.

```
http://www.from.com/?test=ABC
```

goes to

```
http://www.destination.com/main.php?test=ABC&utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=yyy&utm_campaign=zzz
```

instead of

```
http://www.destination.com/main.php?utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=yyy&utm_campaign=zzz&test=ABC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the query arguments manually, but you will need to use a `map` to calculate whether an `&` separator is required.

The `map` should be placed in the `http` block:

```
map $is_args $separator {
    default "";
    "?"     "&";
}
```

The `rewrite` would then look something like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /some/url.php?$args${separator}q=$1? permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: Works perfect.  Can you elaborate what the `map` block where `"?"` and `"&"` do? Is `map` applying certain condition here?

Comment: @KDX the $is_args variable is set to "?" if a query string is present. We need to map that to a "&" to join our argument to the existing query string ($args) unless it's empty.

Comment: Is that meant `$separator` will be `""` if there's no query string?  If there's is query string, `$separator` will become `"&"`.  Am I understanding correctly?